# Getting 404 when accessing Flask app behind nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, virtualenv, uwsgi

I have configured a vhost under nginx thus:

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server-tokens   off;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/api.example.com.access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/api.example.com.error.log;
        index           index.html index.htm;
        server_name     api.example.com;
        autoindex       on;

        location / {
                include         uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass      unix:/var/www/api.example.com/xxx.sock;
        }
}
```

This file is under `sites-available` and `sites-enabled`.

I have configured `uwsgi` thus:

```
[uwsgi]
chmod-socket = 666
socket = /var/www/api.example.com/xxx.sock
processes = 5
threads = 10
master = True
module = xxx 
callable = app 
chdir = /var/www/api.example.com
venv = /home/xxx/.virtualenvs/xxx
thunder-lock = True
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
plugins = http,python
vhost = True
```

I can get uwsgi and nginx to start successfully, but when I go to http://api.example.com I always get an nginx 404. I assume they're both talking through the same socket as no errors happen in relation to it. I can also see .pyc files being generated under `/var/www/api.example.com/` and `/var/www/api.example.com/app` where I keep my views and models.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: Flask and uwsgi had different application names. When I replied they had the same name above I had forgotten to restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but this nginx conf might work. If not, take a look at the nginx and uwsgi logs.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name api.xxxx.com;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 250M;
```

```
root /var/www/api.xxx.com/;
index index.html index.htm;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy; 
}

location @proxy {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/api.xxx.com/xxx.sock

    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```

}

Comment: Now I'm getting 403 - which is still better than 404.

Comment: 403 means its an authentication error, are you using flask-login or something to do authentication?

Comment: Nope, just raw Flask with SQLAlchemy and Redis. Could it be that?

Comment: Turning on directory indexing on nginx show a listing of all files in that directory, clicking on a .py file it gets downloaded - so I suppose the request is not getting to uwsgi?

Comment: Just curious, what happens if you remove the uid and gid params in the uwsgi conf?

Answer (score 1):

first of all make sure your nginx has HttpUwsgiModule, you can check this by running command "`nginx -V`". it will list the all the configured modules.

here is good link http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUwsgiModule